# Java ActionListener issues

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I created a frame. within the frame there is a combobox.
I am trying that each option from the combobox will create something else (JCheckBox,JRadioButton).

```
                        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            String selection = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            label3.setText(input[comboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);


            //panel_mid.removeAll();


            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Pilot")){
                panel_mid.removeAll();
                panel_mid.add(label3,BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel_mid.add(text_bottom);
                panel_mid.setBorder(new TitledBorder(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() + " options"));
                panel_mid.add(jchkCaptain);


            }

            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Host")){
                panel_mid.removeAll();
                panel_mid.add(label3,BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel_mid.add(text_bottom);
                panel_mid.setBorder(new TitledBorder(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() + " options"));

                panel_mid.add(regular = new JRadioButton("Regular"));
                panel_mid.add(bachir = new JRadioButton("Bachir"));
                panel_mid.add(calcelan = new JRadioButton("Calcelan"));

            }
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Office")){
                panel_mid.removeAll();
                panel_mid.add(label3,BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel_mid.add(text_bottom);
                panel_mid.setBorder(new TitledBorder(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() + " options"));

            }
        }



    });
```

when picked Pilot only JCheckBox shuold appear.
when picked Host only JRadioButton shuold appear.
when picked Office nothing shuold appear.

the problem is when i pick host and then pilot and then host it doesnt show the JRadioButton.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

- you have to tell the `LayoutManager` something is/are changed, `LayoutManager` haven't any notifier about, you have to notify programatically about this changes
- use `container.revalidate()` and `container.repaint(variable for JPanels in your case)` as last code line, only one time ,after all changes to the already visible Swing GUI are done
- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for to switch between views (`JPanel`s in your case)